# Squid TPROXY on Ubuntu Router/Gateway

Tags: iptables, squid, ubuntu-14.04, transparent-proxy

Okay, so I have an Ubuntu box acting as Router/Gateway for my LAN; with 3 network cards, 2 for WAN and 1 for the local network. It is setup to load balance between the WAN and failover when needed. And oh, I had to add squid into the equation. It is currently setup to nat redirect http/s ports to squid port like so:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3126
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3127
```

I believe it is working fine... but I don't want to stop there. I would like to try TPROXY, but I cannot seem to make it work. I am getting no traffic in access.log and clients are timing out accessing sites.

Triangle routing is out of the question, and I don't think I should be using bridge? So below is my attempt in doing it:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --on-ip 0.0.0.0 --on-port 3126 --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j TPROXY --on-ip 0.0.0.0 --on-port 3127 --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1

# this is supposed to mark wan traffic going back to lan?
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth2 -p tcp -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1/0x1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth3 -p tcp -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1/0x1

ip rule add fwmark 0x1/0x1 table 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

Well, I am not sure if TPROXY is even possible with my setup. If it ain't possible, I'm gonna have to give up for now. But if it is, anybody would know how?

[If your network topology uses a squid box sitting the inside the router which passes packets to Squid. Then you will need to explicitly add some additional configuration.](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4#Timeouts_with_Squid_not_running_in_the_router_directly)
Like what configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: If anyone interested, here's my current routing/firewall rule: [link](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23261109/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it working - I've used the divert chain in the wiki but explicitly defined the 2 interfaces for the internet connection :)

For those interested, here's my final routing/firewall rule: [click here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23273145/)